# Backgroundworker and Progress bar animate with the progress of external exe

Tags: c#, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I am calling an external exe in C# in **Visual Studio 2010**. i have a backgroundworker and a progress bar. I want to animate the progressbar with the start of the execution of external exe to the end of execution of exe. my code is

```
 private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "d:\\fix.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-l";
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        p.Start();
        p.BeginOutputReadLine();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

how can i control the progress bar, kindly guide me

Comment: Achieving this will depend on the output of the exe and your ability to parse it to find the actual progress. Without more information we cannot help you really.

Comment: how are you planning to get the information about the external executable progress. Is there any callback, or any common place where you can look for progress ? Like is executable writing its progress to a common db, writing to common log file, writing to MSMQ ?

Comment: well it is a console application which prints on console a simple message but after random time

Comment: BackgroundWorker has a `ReportProgress`-Method, which will call the  `ProgressChanged`-Event, which will call a method to update your ProgressBar. But you have nothing to update because there is no visible progress returned by your .exe. Why do you call an external program?

Comment: this is requirement of my project, i have to call this application

Comment: You need to know something about the progress to report on it.  If your .exe gives no feedback then a progressbar sounds like the wrong choice.  Maybe a blinking cursor is more appropriate until completion?  [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/58271/C-Windows-Form-is-Busy]

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, how can i control the progressbar, like this

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Backgroundworker bgw = ctype(sender,backgroundworker);
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "d:\\fix.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-l";
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        p.Start();
        // report progress by calling reportprogress()
        bgw.ReportProgress('Integer value to be passed and used for the progressbar')
        p.BeginOutputReadLine();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Now, since fix.exe is not in a loop that can increment a value its gonna be hard to have a accurate peogressbar. One idea if you absolutley must have it then,

1. Set progressbar maximum value to 10
2. Use te bgw.ReportProgress() in several steps in the DoWork event

   ```
   private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
       {
           Backgroundworker bgw = ctype(sender,backgroundworker);
           Process p = new Process();
           p.StartInfo.FileName = "d:\\fix.exe";
           // report progress by calling reportprogress()
           bgw.ReportProgress(2);
           p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-l";
           p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
           // report progress by calling reportprogress()
           bgw.ReportProgress(5);
           p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
           p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
           p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
           p.Start();
           // report progress by calling reportprogress()
           bgw.ReportProgress(7);
           p.BeginOutputReadLine();
       }

       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           progressBar1.Maximum = 10
           backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
       }

       private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
       {
           progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
       }

       private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
       {

           progressBar1.Value = 10;
       }
   ```

This will in a way increment the progressbar but the progress will always look the same of course.

Comment: well i didnt implement this idea, because i was not sure about the time it wod take, so rather than going for this approach i just simply place a progressbar gif, so that the user may know that there is some background process running

Comment: Ok cool, allthough it wouldnt take more than 5 minutes to implement this but ok.....